# angular: get back array from json but can't pass it into an objectArray from model

Tags: json, angular, typescript

This is my code:

```
users: User[];
    constructor(userService: UserService) {
        userService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(
                users => this.users
            );;
```

In my console I am getting back an array with all my users but my usersArray ist still undefined. Why?

Comment: `this.users = users` ?

Comment: this is because you are not setting it

Comment: why you use twice "users => console.log(users),
                users => this.users".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `users => this.users = users`, but that isnt the only issue.

Entry 2 of the subscribe function is for error logging, so you will want to use

```
userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(users => {
            console.log(users);
            this.users = users;
        },
        error => console.log(error)
    );
```

This will allow you to do multiple things within the "success" entry of the function

```
users => {
    console.log(users);
    this.users = users;
}
```

Could quite easily become

```
users => this.users = users
```